# Double light switch only works one side, even if you flip the cables

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

I have a WiFi enabled double light switch, randomly some months back one room stopped lighting up.

We have since tried replacing the whole switch which stops everything working and also to use the original but with each set of cables wired to different sides and the same side.

No matter what we do the left switch will only ever light up the left room, even if we swap the cables around.

Some how it will still only light the same room with the original switch and not the other side at all, we even tried wiring both cables into the same side but it would still not light the right side room.

We also swapped out the light bulbs to see if they'd all blown on one side, but that too didn't resolve the matter.

Does anyone have any ideas what the heck could be going on?

Comment: Please specify what kind of switch (model, link), and if you upload a pic of your local setup that would help too.

Comment: You should include everything you know about the wiring and how you have hooked it up.  Say for example, this is the two gang switch box.  I've identified line and neutral from the panel, this set of wires is an always on leg to feed plugs, these are the line and neutral switch 1 feeds, and these are switch 2.

Comment: Some of those smart switches need a neutral connection. Answering P2000s and K Hs questions should help get your problem resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, don't trust 2nd hand information.

Basically it was incorrectly wired to start with before I tried looking at the issue, by my brother who claimed he copied the wiring to be identical to the previous device before it broke.

Main issue is the switch has a slave port that shouldn't be used, but was wired up to 1 light.

Still not 100% why when flipping the cables around in it still lit only the 1 room, but I'm guessing it might be something like the power always starting with 1 room before allowing the 2nd to be powered?

Also didn't help that we had a faulty or damaged switch, either from being 2nd hand or from incorrectly using the slave port.

Tried a new basic 2 switch and got it working then got a brand new smart switch and wired it up correctly from the beginning and it all worked.

Since I think the device is terrible anyway I'm also going to list the item and recommend others avoid using it.

My main reason being you have to wait 5 seconds between button presses just to turn on/off both lights.

MIHO072 - Energenie MiHome Smart Chrome 2-Gang light switch.